# Invalid Mapping Exception in hibernate.hbm.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, hbm2ddl

I am posting my hbm file with the cfg file along with my error log. I found my questions based on similar problems are tried out their solution too but still my error is not fading away.

log

```
Initial SessionFactory creation   failed.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource net/viralpatel/hibernate/Employee.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at   net.viralpatel.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:18)
  at net.viralpatel.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
at net.viralpatel.hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:13)
 Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource net/viralpatel/hibernate/Employee.hbm.xml
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:569)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1584)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1552)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1531)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1505)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1411)
at net.viralpatel.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:14)
... 2 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:508)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:566)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 9 of document  : The element type "generator" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</generator>". Nested exception: The element type "generator" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</generator>".
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:499)
... 10 more
```

Employee.hbm.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE" >
    <id name="employeeId" column="EMPLOYEE_ID">
       <generator class="native"> 
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="employeeDetail" class="net.viralpatel.hibernate.EmployeeDetail"
        cascade="save-update"></one-to-one>

    <property name="firstname" column="firstname" />
    <property name="lastname" column="lastname" />
    <property name="birthDate" type="date" column="birth_date" />
    <property name="cellphone" column="cell_phone" />
    </class>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
   <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property    name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property   name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">tcs@1234</property>

    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping resource="net/viralpatel/hibernate/EmployeeDetail.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="net/viralpatel/hibernate/Employee.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `Employee.hbm.xml` you're not closing the generator tag.
Replace

```
<generator class="native">
```

by this

```
<generator class="native"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at stack trace, you have not end the generator tag properly.

Please change your employee.hbm.xml file to end the `<generator>` element properly.

For Ex: It should be `<generator class="native"/>`